# Cypher program fails on non digit argv check

Tags: c, cs50

I need to create a program that takes a command line argument to shift the letters of an input text creating a cyphered output. 
I am getting an error on the "handles non-numeric key - timed out while waiting for program to exit" on the code below. I have added another check to iterate through argv in order to see if it is a digit (isdigit) or not but it still doesn´t work.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int k = atoi(argv[1]); // store key value in K as an int
    int i;
    int key;
    for (key=0; key < strlen(argv[1]); key++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][key] == 0))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    string plaintext = get_string("Type your text: ");  // get text input
    printf("ciphertext: ");      // print title to get cyphered text

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((((plaintext[i] + k) - 97) % 26) + 97)); // formula to convert to alphab and then back to ascii
            }
            else if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((((plaintext[i] + k) - 65) % 26) + 65)); // formula to convert to alphab and then back to ascii
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]); // print as is
        }
    }

    printf("\n"); //exit
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: FYI: `strtol` function combines integer conversion with a check on format. In any case your isdigit check seems fine to me... Could you please clarify what happens when "it doesn't work"? What is the expected behavior in case of non numeric key?

Comment: That's a nasty typo: The `== 0` is in the innermost pair of parens, which means it's part of the argument to `isdigit.` Make that `(isdigit(argv[1][key]) == 0)`.

Comment: @MOhem nice shot! I missed it.

Comment: @MOehm thanks!!! now it works. wow